# Pandas drop and update rows and columns based on column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Here is sample csv file of cricket score:

```
>>> df
 venue  ball  run extra wide  noball
0   a   0.1     0   1   NaN     NaN
1   a   0.2     4   0   NaN     NaN
2   a   0.3     1   5   5.0     NaN
3   a   0.4     1   0   NaN     NaN
4   a   0.5     1   1   NaN     1.0
5   a   0.6     2   1   NaN     NaN
6   a   0.7     6   2   1.0     1.0
7   a   0.8     0   0   NaN     NaN
8   a   0.9     1   1   NaN     NaN
9   a   1.1     2   2   NaN     NaN
10  a   1.2     1   0   NaN     NaN
11  a   1.3     6   1   NaN     NaN
12  a   1.4     0   2   NaN     2.0
13  a   1.5     1   0   NaN     NaN
14  a   1.6     2   0   NaN     NaN
15  a   1.7     0   1   NaN     NaN
16  a   0.1     0   5   NaN     NaN
17  a   0.2     4   0   NaN     NaN
18  a   0.3     1   1   NaN     NaN
19  a   0.4     3   0   NaN     NaN
20  a   0.5     0   0   NaN     NaN
21  a   0.6     0   2   2.0     NaN
22  a   0.7     6   1   NaN     NaN
23  a   1.1     4   0   NaN     NaN
```

From this dataframe I want to update ball value, generate 2 new columns and drop 4 entire columns. Condition is

1. **when "wide" or "noball" is null, crun = crun + run + extra until ball
   = 0.1 (recursively)**
2. **when "wide" or "noball" is not null, concurrent ball value won't be incremented and will be dropped after crun calculation. crun = crun + run + extra. And it will continue until ball = 0.1 (recursively) eg. Let me breakdown: from row index 0 to 8: | 0.1 "wide" or "noball" is null and crun = 1 | 0.2 "wide" or "noball" is null and crun = 1+4 =5| 0.3 "wide" or "noball" is not null (removed) | 0.4 "wide" or "noball" is null (becomes 0.3) and crun = 5+1+5+1 = 12| 0.5 "wide" or "noball" is not null (removed) | 0.6 "wide" or "noball" is null (becomes 0.4) and crun = 12+1+1+2+1 =17| 0.7 "wide" or "noball" is not null (removed) | 0.8 "wide" or "noball" is null (becomes 0.5) and crun = 17+6+2 = 25| 0.9 "wide" or "noball" is null (becomes 0.6) and crun = 25+1+1 =27|**
3. **Finally "total" column will be created which returns the max of crun until ball = 0.1 (recursively). Then "run", "extra", "wide", "noball" column should be dropped.**

The output I want:

```
  venue ball  crun total
0   a   0.1     1   45
1   a   0.2     5   45
2   a   0.3     12  45
3   a   0.4     17  45
4   a   0.5     25  45
5   a   0.6     27  45
6   a   1.1     31  45
7   a   1.2     32  45
8   a   1.3     39  45
9   a   1.4     42  45
10  a   1.5     44  45
11  a   1.6     45  45
12  a   0.1     5   27
13  a   0.2     9   27
14  a   0.3     11  27
15  a   0.4     14  27
16  a   0.5     14  27
17  a   0.6     23  27
18  a   1.1     27  27
```

I find it too complex, please help. Code I tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
gr = df.groupby(df.ball.eq(0.1).cumsum())
df["crun"] = gr.runs.cumsum()
df["total"] = gr.current_run.transform("max")
df = df.drop(['run', 'extra', 'wide', 'noball'], axis=1)
```

Comment: it is a bit unclear how the value in the column ball goes from 0.6 to 1.1 in your result dataframe row index 5-6? could you explain

Comment: Let me breakdown: from row index 0 to 8: | 0.1 "wide" or "noball" is null and crun = 1 | 0.2 "wide" or "noball" is null and crun = 1+4 =5| 0.3 "wide" or "noball" is not null (removed) | 0.4 "wide" or "noball" is null (becomes 0.3) and crun = 5+1+5+1 = 12| 0.5 "wide" or "noball" is not null (removed) | 0.6 "wide" or "noball" is null (becomes 0.4) and crun = 12+1+1+2+1 =17| 0.7 "wide" or "noball" is not null (removed) | 0.8 "wide" or "noball" is null (becomes 0.5) and crun = 17+6+2 = 25| 0.9 "wide" or "noball" is null (becomes 0.6) and crun = 25+1+1 =27| @Ben.T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alrighty.  This was a fun one.

(I tried to add comments for clarity.)

**Note**: "ball," "run," "extra," "wide," and "noball" are all *numeric* fields.

**Note** **Note**: This all assumes your initial DataFrame is under a variable named `df`.

```py
    # Create target groupings by ball value.
    df["target_groups"] = df.loc[df["ball"] == 0.1].groupby(level=-1).ngroup()
    df["target_groups"].fillna(method="ffill", inplace=True)
    

    # --- Create subgroups --- #
    df["target_subgroups"] = df["ball"].astype(int)


    # Add field fro sum of run and extra
    df["run_extra"] = df[["run", "extra"]].sum(axis=1)
    
    # Apply groupby() and cumsum() as follows to get the cumulative sum
    # of each ball group for run and extra.
    df["crun"] = df.groupby(["target_groups"])["run_extra"].cumsum()
    
    # Create dataframe for max crun value of each group
    group_max_df = df.groupby(["target_groups"])["crun"].max().to_frame().reset_index()
    
    # Merge both of the DataFrames with the given suffixes.  The first one
    # Just prevents crun from having a suffix added, which is an additional
    # step to remove.
    # You could probably use .join() in a similar manner.
    df = pd.merge(df, group_max_df,
        on=["target_groups"],
        suffixes=("", "_total"),
        sort=False
    )
    # Rename your new total field.
    df.rename(columns={"crun_total": "total"}, inplace = True)
    
    # Apply your wide and noball condition here.
    df = df[(df["wide"].isna()) & (df["noball"].isna())].copy()
    

    # -- Reset `ball` column -- #
    # Add temp column with static value
    df["tmp_ball"] = 0.1

    # Generate cumulative sum by subgroup.
    # Set `ball` to modulo 0.6
    df.loc[:, "ball"] = df.groupby(["target_subgroups"])["tmp_ball"].cumsum() % 0.6

    # Find rows where ball == 0.0 and set those to 0.6
    df.loc[df["ball"] == 0.0, "ball"] = 0.6

    # Add ball and target_subgroups columns to get final ball value.
    df["ball"]  = df["ball"] + df["target_subgroups"]


    # Reset your main index, if desired
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)


    # Select only desired field for output.
    df = df.loc[:, ["venue","ball","crun","total"]].copy()
```

Output of `df`:

```
   venue  ball  crun  total
0      a   0.1     1     45
1      a   0.2     5     45
2      a   0.4    12     45
3      a   0.6    17     45
4      a   0.8    25     45
5      a   0.9    27     45
6      a   1.1    31     45
7      a   1.2    32     45
8      a   1.3    39     45
9      a   1.5    42     45
10     a   1.6    44     45
11     a   1.7    45     45
12     a   0.1     5     27
13     a   0.2     9     27
14     a   0.3    11     27
15     a   0.4    14     27
16     a   0.5    14     27
17     a   0.7    23     27
18     a   1.1    27     27
```

EDIT:

Comment: Thanks a million! Btw output of the ball value seems not updated. There should be consecutive numbers such as 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 instead of 0.1 0.2 0.4 0.6 0.8 0.9 How can I do this? @MarkMoretto

Comment: Hmm...good catch.  I'll have to take a look, but is there a reason that you can think of that would cause the new "ball" values to cycle from `0.1 - 0. 6` and `1.1 - 1.6` before resetting?  Or, did this example just happen to work out like that?

Comment: Basically, there is a rule in Cricket match each over consists of 6 consecutive **legal** balls. Whereas "wide" and "noball" are illegal. That's why illegal balls should be removed and reindex the ball values. Hope you've got a bit idea.

Comment: @pythonnoob Okay, I updated the answer to adjust the ball column.  There's a subgroup column added, then some rudimentary math for adjusting the final values.